# New to python but how would I get this conditional to print off a certain output

Tags: python

```
import random
def fight():
    print("What's your move")
    print('A. Punch \nB. Submission \nC. Kick')
    response = input()
    reaction = ["Macgregor evades your move", "Macgregor punches back", "Macgregor kicks back", "Macgregor gets knocked out"]
    if response == "Punch" or response == "punch" or response == "submission" or response == "Submission" or response == "kick" or response == "Kick":
        print(random.choice(reaction)) 
        if reaction == "Macgregor gets knocked out":
            print("Merryweather shocks the whole world. He wins!! Tonight was an eventful day and one man had to show he is the best in the world. Tonight the man is John Merryweather")
             
fight()
```

after user gets the reaction macgregor gets knocked out i wanted it to print that last print statement

Comment: `reaction` is the full list of possibilities, and picking a `choice` from it later doesn't change what `reaction` itself refers to.  You probably want to do `reaction = random.choice(["Macgregor evades ...", "..."])` rather than setting it to the full list in the first place.

Comment: your code is a bit messy, python has a lot of power, try looking for how to ignore case sensetive, working with loops, also when you post an issue try to give us the porpuse, what have you done to try and solve the problem, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Reaction is a `list` so comparing against a `string` wont work as you expect.
Use a new variable for the result of `random.choice`:

```
import random


def fight():
    print("What's your move")
    print('A. Punch \nB. Submission \nC. Kick')
    response = input()
    #reactions = ["Macgregor evades your move", "Macgregor punches back", "Macgregor kicks back", "Macgregor gets knocked out"]
    reactions = ["Macgregor gets knocked out"]
    if response == "Punch" or response == "punch" or response == "submission" or response == "Submission" or response == "kick" or response == "Kick":
        reaction = random.choice(reactions)
        print(reaction)
        if reaction == "Macgregor gets knocked out":
            print(
                "Merryweather shocks the whole world. He wins!! Tonight was an eventful day and one man had to show he is the best in the world. Tonight the man is John Merryweather"
            )


fight()
```

Out:

```
punch
Macgregor gets knocked out
Merryweather shocks the whole world. He wins!! Tonight was an eventful day and one man had to show he is the best in the world. Tonight the man is John Merryweather
```